# neo4j graphity how to implement

Tags: graph, neo4j, feed

so I have been trying for quite some time to impelement the `Graphity` on neo4j
But i can find a way to build the queries, anyone have any leads?

for example on the neo4j document for [Graphity](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-graphity.html) there is a query just to get only the first element on the chain. how do i get the second one?

and also why there is an `order by` in the query? isn't that algorithm suppose to eliminate that?

Here is the query:

`MATCH p=(me { name: 'Jane' })-[:jane_knows*]->(friend),(friend)-[:has]->(status)
RETURN me.name, friend.name, status.name, length(p)
ORDER BY length(p)`

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

That is a [variable-length](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/introduction-pattern.html#_variable_length) query (notice the `*` in the relationship pattern), and it gets all the elements in the chain in N result rows (where N is the length of the chain). Each result row's path will contain the previous row's path (if there was a previous row) plus the next element in the chain. And, because every row has a different path length, ordering by the path length makes sense.

If you want to see the names (in order) of **all** the statuses for each friend, this query should do that:

```
MATCH p=(me { name: 'Jane' })-[:jane_knows*]->(friend) 
WITH me, friend, LENGTH(p) AS len 
MATCH (friend)-[:has|next*]->(status) 
RETURN me.name, friend.name, COLLECT(status.name), len
ORDER BY len;
```

With the same data as in the linked example, the result is:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| me.name | friend.name | COLLECT(status.name)  | len |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| "Jane"  | "Bill"      | ["Bill_s1","Bill_s2"] | 1   |
| "Jane"  | "Joe"       | ["Joe_s1","Joe_s2"]   | 2   |
| "Jane"  | "Bob"       | ["Bob_s1"]            | 3   |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: but what if i want the second degree of the users statuses ( the next relationship in the question link)?

Comment: Each result row does contain info for each status as well. See the results in that linked page.

Comment: i do not see any _s2 at the result

Comment: looking good, just one more thing, from my understanding each user at the example holds his timeline sorted.. Does it helps neo4j in sorting the final result?

Comment: I don't think this query will give me what i need beacuse it wont sort the statuses it will sort the users..

Comment: The statuses should be automatically ordered (according to their order in the status chain for each friend), since the variable-length match generates paths incrementally. In fact, the `ORDER BY` in the query is probably not needed. I have modified my answer again.

Comment: but what about the order between the statuses them self(disregarding the the users)? if teds_s2 is before joe_s2?

Comment: The statuses should also be ordered. (BTW: I have updated my query to include the `next` relationship type.)

Comment: I think you missed what im trying to achive... Im trying to implement the `graphity` algorithem: http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/graphity-an-efficient-graph-model-for-retrieving-the-top-k-news-feeds-for-users-in-social-networks/

Comment: See my latest version of the answer, which includes sample output.

Comment: This is still missing something.. Since you cant tell if `bill_s2` was before `joe_s2`, I expected to result to return all the status sorted (assume they have some timestamp) but in the direction I dont see any other choise then doing something like `ORDER BY status.timestamp` and that will make the query run in `n log(n)` and not in `O(1)`

Comment: This is turning into a very different question than what you first presented. You should create a new question.

Comment: well thats exactly what is behind the link in the original question